# How to make my Places api set an always visible option on Autocomplete fragment?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-places-api

Hi im using the new google places api with dependency

`implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'`

Now i have my map alredy setted but i wanna add my places api "MY location" option always VISIBL, and the 2nd option "Click your location" visible as well and obtain a certatin position when that option is clicked  those 2 choices always have to be visible even tho the user its getting autcompleted the search.

heres my code so far:

for places api only

Java code:

`

```
     final AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment= (AutocompleteSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment1);


    autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME,Place.Field.LAT_LNG));







    // Entrega


    final AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment1= (AutocompleteSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment2);

    autocompleteFragment1.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME,Place.Field.LAT_LNG));







    // Fragment De Partida Origen

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {...`
```

this code is only for getting places i already initialized with my api key

and xml code (Note that there 2 fragments so i ll only post one fragment):

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/idCardView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"


    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment1"


    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"

    />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have set up a Google map and Place Autocomplete in  your app, but now you'd also like to implement the option to always find the user's current location? Have you looked into the Current Place service? https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/current-place